# Image sorter by created date in python

Tags: python, image, sorting, properties

I need to make a program that sort all the .jpg files in a directory, or simply all the files in the directory(because they are all jpg, so it doesnt have to be specifically fro jpgs) and that depending on the date they were made, puts them in two separate folders: say for example before 2012 in one folder, and after 2012 in the other....the thing that i dont know how to do is how to i get the program to read through the properties of of all of the files/.jpgs in the folder , after that i think i know what to do : store the dates in a variable , create the two folders and then i was thinking of an if statemente that transfers the files comparing their dates. But how do i tell the program to do this for every file,no matter how many they are?...because i dont know how many files there are in the folder. thanks!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is some quick code to get you in the right direction. It goes through all files in a folder and moves them into two separate subfolders. You can modify this to use modify-date instead of create-date, or to get just .jpg files if you need.

```
import os, datetime

folder_name = "MY_PATH"
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_name):
    file_name_full = os.path.join(folder_name, file_name)
    if not os.path.isfile(file_name_full):
        continue
    timestamp = os.path.getctime(file_name_full)
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    # print out the datestamp
    print dt

    # if you now want to put them into subfolders based on the year 2012 
    # you can do something like the following
    yr = dt.year
    subfolder_name = ""
    if yr < 2012:
        subfolder_name = "before 2012"
    else:
        subfolder_name = "2012 and after"
    subfolder_name_full = os.path.join(folder_name, subfolder_name)
    new_file_name_full = os.path.join(subfolder_name_full, file_name)
    # I assume your folders are premade. If not, you can do a quick-and-dirty mkdir here

    print "Moving %s -> %s" % (file_name_full, new_file_name_full)
    os.rename(file_name_full, new_file_name_full)
```